Cannot display images on QGIS as action
I've been following through the QGIS training manual, section 5.4.
I've created three features on the map, and have associated images with these features as attributes.
I have set up an action in the properties tab to open the images associated with the features when they are clicked. However, the action does not seem to work and I cannot figure out why.
When I leave a space between open and [%image%], the features do nothing when clicked and the 'run feature action' is activated. If I do not leave a space, it gives me a notification that the command cannot be run.



Does open '[%image%]' work?

@bugmenot123 I just checked and unfortunately not.

I solved this issue by switching the action type from Mac to OpenURL, and entering [%image%].

You are missing a space between open and [%image%].

Under Action, write open. Remember to put a space after the command!

